# How to sort values of just certain rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that includes US States, and then counties within each State, and the population of each county.  How can I sort the population data by each county? As all population is in one column, how can I sort the data of only several rows for the counties belonging to one state? For example, the simplified dataframe is like this:

Output:

```
State.   County.   Population 
Alabama. Antauga.  54571
Alabama. Baldwin.  182265
Alabama. Coosa.    11549
Arizona. Apache.   71518
Arizona. Cochise.  131345
Arizona. Glla.     53555
California Alameda 221456
California Butte.  23445
California.Kings.  55343
```

Expected Output:

```
State.   County.   Population 
Alabama. Baldwin.  182265
Alabama. Autauga.  54571
Alabama. Coosa.    11549
Arizona. Cochise.  131345
Arizona. Apache.   71518
Arizona. Glla.     53555
California Alameda 221456
California.Kings.  55343
California Butte.  23445
```

I'd like to sort the population of the counties by their state. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: kindly post what ur expected output should look like. and no pics, only data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(['STATE', 'Population'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you, so I can sort by two columns.  Thanks so much!